Does this AMM for launching new tokens makes any sense?
I have created a smart contract suitable for launching new tokens. Its pricing is similar to uniswapv2, but all pairs are in a single smart contract. The main difference is that when a new token is launched, there is no need to add liquidity of the pairing token. Just set a starting price for the newly launched token and the pair is created with virtual liquidity of the pairing token (the launched token need to be supplied fully to the contract in order to have fair pricing). When people buy the token, they add real liquidity and the price gets higher. When people sell the token, they get from the real liquidity.
Here is the contract: github.com/simplepools/simplepools/blob/main/simplepools-smartcontracts/SimplePools.sol
The main function that manipulates the price and executes the trades is exchangeAsset. You can check it and tell me what you think about this approach for listing new tokens. Do you think that it has a potential to become a platform for launching new meme tokens, or I should start working on something else?
Thanks
